# Why do I get an date conversion error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns:

- `PNum varchar(12)` (persons birthday in the format YYYYMMDDNNNN)
- `DFrom varchar(8)` (start date in the format YYYYMMDD)
- `DEnd varchar(8)` (end date in the format YYYYMMDD)

I try to execute the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    d.PNum, d.DEnd, d.DFrom 
FROM d
WHERE 
    (d.PNum LIKE '1995%' AND (d.DFrom <= DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE()))
ORDER BY 
    d.PNum
```

and I get:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

If I change the condition to

```
WHERE (d.PNum LIKE '199%' AND (d.DFrom <= DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE()))
```

I,e  retrieve all with PNum beginning with 199 I will get the results, including those records that have a PNum beginning with 1995..

Depending on what I use I will either retrieve records or a date conversion error. For instance:

```
d.PNum LIKE '199507%' ...
```

Will work (there are several records).. but

```
d.PNum LIKE '199512%'
```

will not work (there are several records).

Note, the error will only occur when I combine the two conditions. If I remove the (d.DFrom) part it will work just fine. And again, if I use 199% i will get all the records including those that I cannot get when narrowing down the filter.

So it seems to me that SQL Server will interpret the date somehow depending on the PNum filter?? But why?

Thanks for any insight you might give!

/Fridden

Comment: The main problem is that you're using inappropriate data types for your columns. If you want to store dates, use `date`. And I've no idea what the `NNNN` stands for - most people's birthdays are just a date.

Comment: I haven't designed the tables so I cannot take the blame for the inappropriate data type ;-). 

The "NNNN" is a 4 digit number. All citizens in Sweden have a personal number that consists of the birthday plus 3 digits and an additional control digit.
/Fridden

Comment: Then you don't have a formatted date string at all but a denormalized value that can't be treated as a date without first splitting it to its components

Comment: Regarding the PNum field i dont want to treat it as a date. I just want to select those records that have a string beginning with characters 1995 or something else. 

The DFrom field is the field I want to treat as a date and compare it with a date expression. 

What I don't understand is why the DFrom expression is depended on how i express the PNum condition. Why would the interpretation of the date expression on the other side of the AND depend on that string?

Answer (score 3):

1. Always use proper DATETIME datatype to store date and time
2. You need to CAST to DATETIME before comparison.

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.PNum,d.DEnd,d.DFrom FROM d
WHERE d.PNum LIKE '1995%' 
      AND (cast(d.DFrom as datetime) <= DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE())
ORDER BY d.PNum
```

Comment: While this will overcome the initial error, performance will be horrible because the cast will prevent the query optimizer from using any indexes. The only real solution is to fix the type of the fields

Comment: Yes. I agree. That's why I told OP to use proper Datetime datatype in my first point :)

Comment: I am not able to change the datatype, but even so why will the (DFrom < DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETDATE()) depend on how I write the "PNum LIKE '1995%'" part ?

Casting the d.FROM expression doesnt help. 

If I only use the DFrom <= DATEADD(...) condition and remove the "PNum LIKE..." it will work fine. 

Just the combination of both will cause the error, depending on the wildcard.

Comment: I was wrong in my previous comment that "DFRom<=DATEADD" by itself worked. 

It didn't.

But Casting to Datetime didn't worked so I tried instead to cast DATEADD to varchar(8) and it worked.

i.e 
    SELECT DISTINCT d.PNum,d.DEnd,d.DFrom FROM d
    WHERE d.PNum LIKE '1995%' 
      AND (d.DFrom <= CAST((DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(8)))
   ORDER BY d.PNum

Thanks for all the input!
/Fridden

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your datatypes -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    PNum DATETIME,
    DFrom DATE,
    DEnd DATE
)

INSERT INTO @temp (PNum, DFrom, DEnd)
VALUES ('20130112 12:30', '20130112', '20130112');

SELECT DISTINCT PNum, DEnd, DFrom 
FROM @temp
WHERE YEAR(PNum) = 2013 AND DFrom <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETDATE())
ORDER BY PNum
```

Comment: Which is the only real solution - everything else is just a hack